# How to aggregate by day?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Pojo:

```
public class MyPojo {
   Date startDate;
   Double usageAMount;
   // ... bla bla bla
}
```

So I have a list of `MyPojo` objects, passed to a function as an argument:

```
public Map<Date, Double> getWeeklyCost(@NotNull List<MyPojo> reports) {
        JavaRDD<MyPojo> rdd = context.parallelize(reports);
        JavaPairRDD<Date, Double> result = rdd.mapToPair(
                (PairFunction<MyPojo, Date, Double>) x ->
                        new Tuple2<>(x.getStartDate(), x.getUsageAmount()))
                .reduceByKey((Function2<Double, Double, Double>) (x, y) -> x + y);

        return result.collectAsMap();
}
```

However, I return something like:

```
"2017-06-28T22:00:00.000+0000": 0.02916666,
"2017-06-29T16:00:00.000+0000": 0.02916666,
"2017-06-27T13:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-26T05:00:00.000+0000": 0.05833332000000001,
"2017-06-28T21:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-27T02:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-28T03:00:00.000+0000": 0.07777776000000002,
"2017-06-28T20:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-30T04:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-28T02:00:00.000+0000": 0.05833332000000001,
"2017-06-29T21:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-29T23:00:00.000+0000": 0.06805554000000001,
"2017-06-27T00:00:00.000+0000": 0.05833332000000001,
"2017-06-26T06:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-28T01:00:00.000+0000": 0.09722220000000002,
"2017-06-29T22:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-28T00:00:00.000+0000": 0.11666664000000003,
"2017-06-27T12:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-26T11:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-29T03:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-26T04:00:00.000+0000": 0.07777776000000002,
"2017-06-27T19:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-29T20:00:00.000+0000": 0.048611100000000004,
"2017-06-29T02:00:00.000+0000": 0.02916666,
"2017-06-29T15:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-27T17:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-29T14:00:00.000+0000": 0.02916666,
"2017-06-30T01:00:00.000+0000": 0.02916666,
"2017-06-29T00:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-27T18:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-26T03:00:00.000+0000": 0.07777776000000002,
"2017-06-28T05:00:00.000+0000": 0.05833332000000001,
"2017-06-29T13:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-30T03:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-27T11:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-28T04:00:00.000+0000": 0.05833332000000001,
"2017-06-29T12:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-30T02:00:00.000+0000": 0.06805554000000001,
"2017-06-27T23:00:00.000+0000": 0.09722220000000002,
"2017-06-27T16:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-26T15:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-29T06:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-30T07:00:00.000+0000": 0.00138889,
"2017-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-27T21:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-26T02:00:00.000+0000": 0.07777776000000002,
"2017-06-29T19:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-27T03:00:00.000+0000": 0.03888888,
"2017-06-27T20:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-30T05:00:00.000+0000": 74.1458333,
"2017-06-29T18:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-29T17:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-28T23:00:00.000+0000": 0.00972222,
"2017-06-27T01:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
"2017-06-27T22:00:00.000+0000": 0.05833332000000001
```

and I want to return it aggregated by the day, sorted in descending order bu the date.
For example:

```
"2017-06-28T03:00:00.000+0000": 0.07777776000000002,
"2017-06-28T20:00:00.000+0000": 0.01944444,
```

Are in the same day, so their values (usageAmount) should be added. I just care about the day, not about the hour. How can I reduce or aggregate my RDD to obtain the desired result?

** Update ** The answer must be a Spark RDD solution ...

Comment: Can you use Spark SQL's DataFrames? That's be soooo much easier to write and understand later.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The data comes from MongoDB....

Answer (score 0):

Relatively easy (even though it's gonna be a lot of code)

Let's start with an implementation of Pojo:

```
static class Record
{
    private Date date;
    private double amount;
    public Record(Date d, double a)
    {
        this.date = d;
        this.amount = a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date.toString() + "\t" + amount;
    }
}
```

Now a utility method to check whether two Records are in the same day:

```
private static boolean sameDay(Record r0, Record r1)
{
    Date d0 = r0.date;
    Date d1 = r1.date;

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(d0);

    int[] dateParts0 = {cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)};

    cal.setTime(d1);

    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == dateParts0[0] &&
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dateParts0[1] &&
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == dateParts0[2];
}
```

Now that we have that, we can get started on the main bulk of the algorithm.
The idea here is to sort the list of inputs by day. And then loop over the list.
For every entry we're processing we check whether it's the same day as the last known day of our aggregated dataset. If it is, we add the amount of the record, if it's not we add a new entry.

```
public static List<Record> aggregate(Collection<Record> rs)
{
    List<Record> tmp = new ArrayList<>(rs);
    java.util.Collections.sort(tmp, new Comparator<Record>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
            return o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
        }
    });

    List<Record> out = new ArrayList<>();
    out.add(new Record(tmp.get(0).date, 0));
    for(int i=0;i<tmp.size();i++)
    {
        Record last = out.get(out.size() - 1);
        Record recordBeingProcessed = tmp.get(i);
        if(sameDay(last, recordBeingProcessed))
        {
            last.amount += recordBeingProcessed.amount;
        }
        else
        {
            out.add(recordBeingProcessed);
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

And finally, a nice main method to test everything:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String[] dateStrings = {"January 2, 2010", "January 2, 2010", "January 3, 2010"};
    List<Record> rs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<dateStrings.length;i++)
    {
        rs.add(new Record(format.parse(dateStrings[i]), 1));
    }
    for(Record r : aggregate(rs))
    {
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

That prints out:

```
Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 2010    2.0
Sun Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2010    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyPojo {

       Date startDate;
       Double usageAMount;
       static DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd:hh");

    MyPojo(Date startDate, Double usageAMount) {

        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.usageAMount = usageAMount;
    }

    Date getStrartDate() { return startDate;}
    Double getUsage() { return usageAMount;}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        List<MyPojo> reports  = getReports();

        //sort by date
        reports = reports.stream().sorted(getComperator()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        output(reports);

        //you can collect to map but map keys are not sorted
        //and keys (dates) must be unique
        Map<Date, Double> result = reports.stream().sorted(getComperator()).collect(Collectors
                .toMap( e-> e.startDate , e-> e.usageAMount));
    }

    private static List<MyPojo> getReports() throws ParseException {

        List<MyPojo> reports = new ArrayList<>();

        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-28:01"), 0.02916666));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-29:01"), 0.02916666));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-27:01"), 0.03888888));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-26:01"), 0.05833332000000001));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-28:02"), 0.03888888));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-27:02"), 0.03888888));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-28:03"), 0.07777776000000002));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-28:04"), 0.01944444));
        reports.add(new MyPojo(format.parse("2017-06-30:01"), 0.00972222));

        return reports;
    }

    private static Comparator<? super MyPojo> getComperator() {

        Comparator<? super MyPojo> comperator = new Comparator<MyPojo>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(MyPojo o1, MyPojo o2) {

                if((o1 == o2) || ((o1 == null) && (o2 == null))) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if( o1 == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if( o2 == null) {
                    return  1;
                }

                return (o1).startDate.compareTo((o2).startDate);
            }

        };
        return comperator;
    }

    static void output(List<MyPojo> reports) {

        for(MyPojo p : reports) {
            System.out.println(format.format(p.startDate) +" - "+ p.usageAMount);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2017-06-27:01 - 0.03888888 
> 2017-06-27:02 - 0.03888888
>   
> 2017-06-28:01 - 0.02916666 
> 2017-06-28:02 - 0.03888888
>   
> 2017-06-28:03 - 0.07777776000000002 
> 2017-06-28:04 -
>   0.01944444 
> 2017-06-29:01 - 0.02916666 
> 2017-06-30:01 - 0.00972222